# Escaping special characters in an MDX Query

Tags: mdx, msas

I'm building a BI dashboard for my client.  Our data is stored in an analysis server cube.  Overall things work great, but a smartalec tester decided to create a merchant with the name `~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':"<>?,./  The name shows up just fine as a part of a query result, but if the user trys to drill in to the merchant we of course blow up b/c the \ { ; [ " are all part of MDX.  Is there a way to escape these characters?  I've tried putting a \ in front, or doubling the character.  I've searched all over, but not turn up anything.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the [] notation for your names and escape (only) the right bracket. Here is an example declaring a calculated measure with the name to escape (notice the ]] ):

```
with member [`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]]{}|;':"<>?,./] as 42
select [`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]]{}|;':"<>?,./] on 0 from [cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try use [  ] brackets? I think it should help. But you should also "escape" your own brackets.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145572.aspx)

> If the body of the identifier contains only a left bracket ([), no
>   additional handling is required. If the body of the identifier
>   contains a right bracket (]), you must specify two right brackets
>   (]]).