# Escape percentage character (%) in a dynamic mdx query formed in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, mdx

How do i escape "%" character in a dynamic MDX. I want "%" to be treated as a literal and not a wild card in MDX.
Here is a basic idea of what is happening : 
I have a windows form (using c#) where user can create a dynamic search expression for MDX query.
E.g.
Currency *Contains* **US**

where "Currency" is static, condition "Contains" is a dropdown selectable value and then a textbox for "US".

So user clicks "Search" and a dynamic MDX is formed with above condition and a cube hit occurs.

Now, i dont get correct result when query is like :

Calculation *Contains* **50%**

Here, % is treated as wild card and anything containing "50" is shown.
Please Help. I have tried quotes "", square brackets [], back slash \, double characters %%. but no luck.

UPDATE : 
Its actually the front end meaning for the user, at the back end i use Analysis Stored Procedures, "IsLike" for this. Query is something like this : { WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Search] AS IIF( [ASSP].[IsLike] ([Calculation].[Calculation].CurrentMember.Properties('MEMBER_CAP‌​‌​TION'),'%50%%')}

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997814/escaping-special-characters-in-an-mdx-query) can help you?

Comment: `Contains` is not an Analysis Services MDX function. Is this implemented as a stored procedure? Then you would have to ask the developer of that procedure how he wants the text to be escaped.

Comment: Its actually the front end meaning for the user, at the back end, "IsLike" is used for this.

Query is something like this : { WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Search] AS IIF( [ASSP].[IsLike]([Calculation].[Calculation].CurrentMember.Properties('MEMBER_CAP‌​TION'),'%50%%')}

Comment: Earl, i went through this, not much helpful.Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are using the ASSP (Analysis Stored Procedures) IsLike method, and want to know how you can escape a `%` in the like template so that it is searched for literally. Looking at the source code (http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ASSP/StringFilters.cs, method `LikeToRegEx`), I do not see an easy way to achieve this. In this method, a percent is replaced unconditionally by `".*"`. What you could do is download the ASSP source code and change this method to allow escaping the percent e. g. with `"[%]"` which would work in the SQL Server relational engine `like`. 
E. g. you could add after the

```
sb.Replace("[.]", @"_");
```

another line

```
sb.Replace("[\.]", @"%");
```

which would revert the overly aggressive replace of `[%]` with `[.*]`.
Then you would compile this and re-deploy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank. Yes, you got my question correctly.
Let me try this and revert back.

Comment: This probably is the closest i could get to resolving my problem.
Thanks Frank